# MySQL Union alternative due to poor query performance

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, query-optimization

I have a database structure similar to the following:

[image]

and a stored procedure that is querying the data to try and find the upper and lower nearest matching rates. For example:

Age = 6, Distance = 103 for product "Apple" with Price of "600" should return Rate Id 1 and Rate Id 2 (two rows) as these are the rates that fall within the parameters specified. Eg, the rate lower and the rate higher where there is not an exact match.

```
select t.rateId as id, t.Rate as rate, t.Age as age, t.Distance as Distance from (
(select t.*
    from rates t
    where Age <= (in_age + 1) and Distance <= in_Distance and
    in_Price > MinPrice and in_Price <= MaxPrice
    and Product=in_Product and Type=in_Type
    order by Age desc, Distance desc limit 1
) union
(select t.*
    from rates t
    where Age >= (in_age + 1) and Distance <= in_Distance and
    in_Price > MinPrice and in_Price <= MaxPrice
    and Product=in_Product and Type=in_Type
    order by Age asc, Distance desc limit 1
) union
(select t.*
    from rates t
    where Age <= (in_age + 1) and Distance >= in_Distance and
    in_Price > MinPrice and in_Price <= MaxPrice
    and Product=in_Product and Type=in_Type
    order by Age desc, Distance asc  limit 1
) union
(select t.*
    from rates t
    where Age >= (in_age + 1) and Distance >= in_Distance and
    in_Price > MinPrice and in_Price <= MaxPrice
    and Product=in_Product and Type=in_Type
    order by Age asc, Distance asc  limit 1
)) t;
```

Any of the individual selects in the above statement takes 100'ths of a second to run. However, when they are indiviually unioned together, the entire query now takes ~1 second.

Note that depending on the input parameters, the result can be either 1, 2 or 4 rate rows. 1 result would be where there is an exact match for the specified Age and Distance. 2 would be where there is an exact match for one of either Age or Distance and up to 4 results if there isn't an exact match for either Age nor Distance.

I have tried a number of different approaches other than a UNION and am getting equivalent performance. For example, I have tried:

```
...where rateId in (
    ...QRY 1...
) or rateId in (
    ...QRY 2...
) or rateId in (
    ...QRY 3...
) or rateId in (
    ...QRY 4...
);
```

And selecting individually into a temporary table and then returning the contents of the temporary table. However, in all cases, the performance is about the same. ~1 second as opposed to ~0.001 second per each of the 4 queries if run individually!

Any ideas on how I can improve the performance or what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!
Jablar

Sample Data:

```
rateId,Age,Distance,Rate,Product,MinPrice,MaxPrice
269369,95,500,1000,Apple,50,110
269385,95,1000,1058,Apple,50,110
269401,95,1500,1147,Apple,50,110
269417,95,2000,1223,Apple,50,110
269433,95,2500,1225,Apple,50,110
269449,95,3000,1294,Apple,50,110
269465,95,3500,1368,Apple,50,110
269481,95,4000,1436,Apple,50,110
269497,95,4500,1454,Apple,50,110
269513,95,5000,1477,Apple,50,110
269529,95,5500,1559,Apple,50,110
269545,95,6000,1566,Apple,50,110
269561,95,6500,1584,Apple,50,110
269577,95,7000,1614,Apple,50,110
269593,100,500,1637,Apple,50,110
269609,100,1000,1730,Apple,50,110
269625,100,1500,1775,Apple,50,110
269641,100,2000,1794,Apple,50,110
269657,100,2500,1830,Apple,50,110
269673,100,3000,1903,Apple,50,110
269689,100,3500,1912,Apple,50,110
269705,100,4000,1931,Apple,50,110
269721,100,4500,1947,Apple,50,110
269737,100,5000,2047,Apple,50,110
269753,100,5500,2051,Apple,50,110
269769,100,6000,2094,Apple,50,110
269785,100,6500,2152,Apple,50,110
269801,100,7000,2189,Apple,50,110
269817,125,500,2280,Apple,50,110
269833,125,1000,2358,Apple,50,110
269849,125,1500,2412,Apple,50,110
269865,125,2000,2424,Apple,50,110
269881,125,2500,2475,Apple,50,110
269897,125,3000,2485,Apple,50,110
269913,125,3500,2564,Apple,50,110
269929,125,4000,2641,Apple,50,110
269945,125,4500,2735,Apple,50,110
269961,125,5000,2772,Apple,50,110
269977,125,5500,2826,Apple,50,110
269993,125,6000,2837,Apple,50,110
270009,125,6500,2926,Apple,50,110
270025,125,7000,2930,Apple,50,110
270041,150,500,2955,Apple,50,110
270057,150,1000,2973,Apple,50,110
270073,150,1500,3064,Apple,50,110
270089,150,2000,3108,Apple,50,110
270105,150,2500,3180,Apple,50,110
270121,150,3000,3219,Apple,50,110
270137,150,3500,3315,Apple,50,110
270153,150,4000,3389,Apple,50,110
270169,150,4500,3395,Apple,50,110
270185,150,5000,3417,Apple,50,110
270201,150,5500,3442,Apple,50,110
270217,150,6000,3451,Apple,50,110
270233,150,6500,3493,Apple,50,110
270249,150,7000,3519,Apple,50,110
270265,175,500,3568,Apple,50,110
270281,175,1000,3614,Apple,50,110
270297,175,1500,3708,Apple,50,110
270313,175,2000,3763,Apple,50,110
270329,175,2500,3845,Apple,50,110
270345,175,3000,3910,Apple,50,110
270361,175,3500,3934,Apple,50,110
270377,175,4000,3950,Apple,50,110
270393,175,4500,4009,Apple,50,110
270409,175,5000,4077,Apple,50,110
270425,175,5500,4108,Apple,50,110
270441,175,6000,4158,Apple,50,110
270457,175,6500,4239,Apple,50,110
270473,175,7000,4339,Apple,50,110
270489,200,500,4369,Apple,50,110
270505,200,1000,4438,Apple,50,110
270521,200,1500,4510,Apple,50,110
270537,200,2000,4533,Apple,50,110
270553,200,2500,4622,Apple,50,110
270569,200,3000,4690,Apple,50,110
270585,200,3500,4786,Apple,50,110
270601,200,4000,4868,Apple,50,110
270617,200,4500,4955,Apple,50,110
270633,200,5000,5009,Apple,50,110
270649,200,5500,5080,Apple,50,110
270665,200,6000,5151,Apple,50,110
270681,200,6500,5198,Apple,50,110
270697,200,7000,5250,Apple,50,110
270713,225,500,5304,Apple,50,110
270729,225,1000,5349,Apple,50,110
270745,225,1500,5386,Apple,50,110
270761,225,2000,5430,Apple,50,110
270777,225,2500,5499,Apple,50,110
270793,225,3000,5500,Apple,50,110
270809,225,3500,5528,Apple,50,110
270825,225,4000,5582,Apple,50,110
270841,225,4500,5610,Apple,50,110
270857,225,5000,5690,Apple,50,110
270873,225,5500,5736,Apple,50,110
270889,225,6000,5748,Apple,50,110
270905,225,6500,5820,Apple,50,110
270921,225,7000,5868,Apple,50,110
270937,250,500,5911,Apple,50,110
270953,250,1000,5998,Apple,50,110
```

Sample expected results with the above data as follows:

Age = 95, Distance = 500 for product "Apple" with Price of "75"
-> Single result: RateId 269369

Age = 95, Distance = 750 for product "Apple" with Price of "75"
-> Two results: RateId 269369 & 269385 (this basically gives the rates for the nearest lower distance and nearest higher distance as a rate for the exact distance of 750 is not present.

Age = 97, Distance = 750 for product "Apple" with Price of "75"
-> Four results: RateId 269369, 269385, 269593, 269609 (Similar to above, but now also giving next nearest lower and higher for the Age aswell as there is no exact match for Age 97.

Comment: What version of mysql are you on / why not using lead/lag?

Comment: @P.Salmon, I am using MySQL v8. I am not familiar with Lead and Lag, but am looking into them now!

Comment: @P.Salmon, I just read up a little on Lead / Lag and not sure how I would use them in this scenario. I think I can see how to use them instead of the individual LIMIT's, but I cannot see how to use them to reduce the 4 sub-queries down to 1? I may not be understanding, so please do let me know on same.

Comment: Please add sample data as text which I can use..

Comment: @P.Salmon, not problem, sample data added to the original question in CSV form.

Comment: It would be more appropriate if your sample data was the same as the posted image and matched the desired outcome as described in the question.

Comment: **Pro tip**. Sort out your performance problems by running your query outside your stored procedure. Only then use the SP. Otherwise it takes too long to try different things.

Comment: @O.Jones, that is exactly what has been done and why the question provided sample data and sample SQL?

Comment: @P.Salmon. Apologies, was trying to give a broader data set to you. I have updated the question with 3x example expected results based on the new larger data set.

Comment: I don't understand this metric:  `Age <= (in_age + 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Start by focusing on a formula for the 'metric' to sort on.

Note:  A boolean expression evaluates to 1 (for true) or 0 (for false.

```
metric = (age = in_age)   -- increase metric if exact
       + (age <= in_age+1)  -- increase again (I don't grok <=)
       + 2*(distance <= in_distance) -- close enuf counts as 2
       + ...
```

Then do something like

```
SELECT ...,
       (...) AS metric
    FROM ...
    ORDER BY metric
    LIMIT 4;
```

That may be 4 times as fast as what you have -- because it is only 1 query.  But it will still be slow -- because it needs to check each row.  (The complexity of `metrid` is not a big performance factor.)

Comment: thanks for the reply and suggestion. Unfortunatley, I do not understand what you are proposing. Could you explain a little more or maybe give me an example query? Thanks